# Audio по клику на ссылку срабатывает только первый раз

Tags: jquery, аудио, javascript

По непонятной причине аудиофайл, привязанный к событию click на ссылку, срабатывает только при первом клике, а дальше молчит.

```
<audio class="bulk" preload="auto">
  <source src="img/mymusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>

var audio = $(".bulk")[0];
$('a').click(function() {
    audio.play();
});
```

Пробовала

```
var audio = $(".bulk")[0];
$('a').click(function() {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
});
```

Не работает. Не пойму, то ли js объект так долго потом формируется, то ли первый клик надо отменять. Я права? Если нет, направьте, пожалуйста, в нужную сторону.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/L5wRh/

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает вам использовать стандартные кнопки?

```
<audio id="player" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Воспроизведение</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Пауза</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Громкость +</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">Громкость -</button>
</div>
```

источник: http://habrahabr.ru/post/148202/

Comment: так мне на каждую ссылку меню кнопку придется прописывать) А мне нужно. что по клику на кнопку меню играла музыка

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, большое спасибо!